# Checking multiple SQL Server .bak backup files are from the same backup

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

What would be the best way to check that SQL Server `.bak` files are from the same backup? Say I backup a database like this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorksDW2017_2
TO DISK = 'C:\backup\advBackup2Peices\1.bak',
   DISK = 'C:\backup\advBackup2Peices\2.bak',
   DISK = 'C:\backup\advBackup2Peices\3.bak'
GO
```

Now if I run `LABELONLY`, `HEADERONLY` or `FILELISTONLY` on one of these backup files, I would get information about this backup - like this:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY  
FROM DISK = 'C:\backup\advBackup2Peices\1.bak'
```

Without running the actual backup command, I would like to figure out this information below about these files (maybe using the above commands or any other commands)

How can I make sure that all these `.bak` files belong to the same backup?

Also, how to make sure the number of files this backup should contain (like above backup contains 3 files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BackupSetGUID` value of `RESTORE HEADERONLY` is the same for files of the same backup. The `FamilyCount` of `RESTORE LABELONLY` is the number of backup files.